# Page forwarding with transfer of parameters called in URLs from one folder to another

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting, parameter-passing

In my wordpress page, links are addressed in the way:

www.mywebsite.com/blog/?page_id=1234

And each number gives a different page. I would like to have a forwarding mechanism that would forward a page in the form

www.mywebsite.com/mypage/?page_id=1234

when done in the folder "mypage", to the other folder "blog" as:

www.mywebsite.com/blog/?page_id=1234

with transferring each variable I have on the URL (in this case the only variable is page_id, and I would like to have all the variables forwarded to another page).

I'm pretty experienced in HTML and C/C++, but a beginner in PHP (though I've noticed that PHP is very similar to c in its logic, and I've done many changes in my Wordpress page based on my knowledge in C).

*How can I do such a forwarding of code? Is it possible?*

If there's any information missing, please let me know.

Thank you for any efforts.

Comment: wordpress never shows folder name in url of page or post

Comment: I mean a subfolder in the domain that contains my wordpress website.

Comment: why you dont want to move your wordpress installation in blog sub directory ?

Comment: @pr1nc3 for historical reasons... I have a lot of business already going on in my previous URL.

Comment: it can be done via url rewrite but since i am not good with it i would suggest you to update your qstn tags . add `url-rewrite` tag too so that masters can guide you best

Comment: I think that [endpoints](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82748) could be useful. But am not sure as I'm not familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

This website gave a good tutorial on this. It took me 15 minutes to implement the solution.

http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Answer (score -1):

SESSION if you want it to be specific for every user, POST if you dont want to change the url and the same for every user.

Im not really sure I understood your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer at all. Please either provide a reference or explain more.